# Jenkins DSL script - multiple extensions found

Tags: jenkins, dsl

Is there anyway in a DSL script to explicitly specify an extension? I'm trying to use buildTrigger and when Jenkins tries to load the script, an error pops out:

```
ERROR: Found multiple extensions which provide method BuildTrigger ... [hudson.tasks.BuildTrigger, hudson.plugins.parameterizedtrigger.BuildTrigger
```

Initially I used downstreamParameterized but I need to set triggerFromChildProjects which isn't supported in that context.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins DSL script - Test Failure - Found multiple extensions which provide method lastCompleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51564810/jenkins-dsl-script-test-failure-found-multiple-extensions-which-provide-meth)

Comment: Flagging this as a duplicate, even though really... I think this needs a better answer. I'm suffering form the exact same problem you are, and using a `configure` block here is not an option, I think.